# How can I prevent javascript assignment from creating ownProperty

Tags: javascript

Here is an example:

```
var cat1 = Object.create({
  name: "mia"
});

cat1.hasOwnProperty('name') // false
cat1.name = "haha";
cat1.hasOwnProperty('name') // true
```

This is rather surprising to me.

1) What is the design intention here?

2) How can I use `=` without create new properties?

Comment: The design intent is that if you set a property on an object, then you want to set a property on that object, not on some other object. You can use `=` without creating new properties by defining setters that do anything you want.

Comment: @torazaburo My main goal is to avoid walking the proto chain manually.  Looking into setters, now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the design intention here?

I didn't design JavaScript, but my guess would be to restrict the "scope" of mutations. Imagine you had two objects:

```
var proto = {name: "mia"};
var cat1 = Object.create(proto);
var cat2 = Object.create(proto);
```

If assignment to `cat1.name` would *not* create a new property, but update the prototype property instead, then `cat2.name` would suddenly be updated as well.

In other words, if assignment was updating prototype properties instead of the object's own properties, other objects could be affected by the change, without you even knowing it.

> How can I use `=` without create new properties?

You cannot. You could assign to the prototype explicitly, but that requires you to know that the property is defined on the prototype:

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(cat1).name = 'haha';
```

Answer (score 0):

hasOwnProperty shows properties defined on the object. At the same time:

```
Object.create({
  name: "mia"
});
```

Creates new object with prototype `{name: "mia"}`. This means that property `name` will be defined for prototype not for object. Using prototypes makes some sort of optimization. Different object share the same logic from the prototype. Also the  methods are not duplicated, so less memory is used. 
When you defines **own** property by `=` you are showdowing the property with the same name from the prototype, so as @Felix Kling indicated you are not changing property in the prototype and other objects that use the same prototype will not be affected. You also can use `Object.defineProperty(obj, prop, descriptor)` instead of `=` in order to define own property of the object, but you can not use `=` on object without defining new properties you can do that on the prototype directly like this:

```
cat1.__proto__.name="other name" //avoid, this is not the best practive at all
```

Answer (score 0):

By design, When you create object from a prototype, the new objects will share the properties with prototype object until you assign value explicitly to that property on that object, once its assigned since then the object will maintain its own state. below is sample code for the same.

```js
var x = {"name":"mia"};
var o1= Object.create(x);
var o2= Object.create(x);
console.log(x.name,o1.name,o2.name); //output: mia,mia,mia
x.name="xxx";
console.log(x.name,o1.name,o2.name); //output: xxx,xxx,xxx

o1.name="yyy";
console.log(x.name,o1.name,o2.name); //output: xxx,yyy,xxx
```